# Django Rest Framework def update is duplicating objects

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using this method to handle updates in a nested serialisation of a many to many relationship.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    songs = validated_data.pop('suggested_songs')
    updated_instance = super(MessagesSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data) 
    updated_instance.save()
    for song_data in songs:
        s = Song(**song_data)
        s.save()
        updated_instance.suggested_songs.add(s)
```

But I've noticed that when trying to update the data duplicates of songs occur as opposed to editing the existing ones.

I figured one method would to clear "suggested_songs" before add new ones, but ideally I would to edit the existing data correctly, how can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

My second attempt which doesn't work unless I specify the ID:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    suggested_songs_data = validated_data.pop('suggested_songs')
    updated_instance = super(MessagesSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
    updated_instance.save()
    for song_data in suggested_songs_data:
        #songID = song_data.pop('id') # Grabbing the song ID so that we can check if the ID already exists. 
        #print(songID)
        s = Song(**song_data)
        print(song_data)
        print(instance)
        print("HELLO")
        print(suggested_songs_data)
    # If the song already exists we want to edit  
        print("+++ DEBUG ------------------------- DEBUG +++")
        s.id = '20'
        print(s.id)
        print(s.title)
        if Song.objects.filter(id = s.id).exists():
            print("FOUND OBJECT")
            # If the object exists, then we should edit it. 
            foundSong = Song.objects.get(id=s.id)
            print(foundSong.title)
        # We should be editing song. 
            foundSong.title = s.title
            foundSong.artist = s.artist
            foundSong.album = s.album
            foundSong.albumId = s.albumId
            foundSong.num_votes = s.num_votes
            foundSong.cleared = s.cleared
            foundSong.save()
        else:
            # no object satisfying query exists, so lets create a new one. 
            s.save()
            updated_instance.suggested_songs.add(s)
    return updated_instance
```

Comment: The issue is in your `for` loop, you are only creating new songs instead of checking to see if they already exist first.

Comment: How can I check whether the song exists? It has no ID because its autogenerated by DRF.